# Storing resources in XAP package

Tags: silverlight

Is it possible to store resx files and access them from the application package without changing any code?

**EDIT:** I don't want to embed them into the assembly. The resource files should be able to be modified without compiling the project so I tought storing them in XAP and replace when needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to include any file in a XAP by specifying that its build action to be `Content`.

However I'm not sure that is useful to you in the way you are hoping.  Silverlight can only utalise a resx file in the intended manner if it is embedded in a dll.

Instead of using .resx files consider using `ResourceDictionary` .xaml files.

Answer (score -1):

a XAP file is encrypted. you could load resources into isolated storage and access them in a similar way to a resource.

Comment: Standard Silverlight XAP files are simply Zip files.  They are not encrypted.